# How to add two different UIPickerView data into single label?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

[image: i have a two different UIPickerViews as shown image left duration and right duration have same data with different arrays]>    How can i add two UIPickerView data into single label? how to add Hours and minutes into single label ?

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    var hoursSelected1 = ""
    var minsSelected1 = ""

    var hoursSelected2 = ""
    var minsSelected2 = ""

    if strDurationComeFrom == "left"{

        hoursSelected1 = hoursArray1[myPickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        minsSelected1 = minsArray1[myPickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        leftDuration.text = "\(hoursSelected1) \(minsSelected1)"

    }

    else{

        hoursSelected2 = hoursArray2[myPickerView2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
         minsSelected2 = minsArray2[myPickerView2.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]



       rightDuration.text = "\(hoursSelected2) \(minsSelected2)"
    }
    totalDuration = leftDuration.text+rightDuration.text
}
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna assume that `hoursArray` and `minsArray` have integers, if not, just convert them and do this in `titleForRow`. I don't see a reason to have `minsArray1` and `minsArray2`. How can minutes be different? How can hours be different? You can just have one `minsArray` that works as data source for both pickers.

```
if component == 0 {
    return "\(hoursArray[titleForRow]) h"
} else {
    return "\(minsArray[titleForRow]) m"
}
```

Then:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    let hourSelected = hoursArray[row]
    let minSelected = minsArray[row]
    let otherHour: Int
    let otherMin: Int
    let otherPickerView: UIPickerView!
    let labelText = "\(hourSelected)h \(minSelected)m"

    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        leftDuration.text = labelText
        otherPickerView = pickerView2
    } else {
        rightDuration.text = labelText
        otherPickerView = pickerView1
    }

    otherHour = hoursArray[otherPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    otherMin = minsArray[otherPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]

    totalDuration = "\(hoursSelected + otherHour)h \(minSelected + otherMin)m"

}
```

Testing this code would mean reproducing your whole setup and it would take a long time, but I am sure the logic works. If you have any question, let me know.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want to add both (left duration and right duration) hours and mins from and while i am changing picker values it should be updatable

Comment: suppose left duration have 1 hour 10min , right duration have 3 hour 30 mins then total duration 4 hours 40 mins like this i want ,how can i get it? help me

Comment: That is pretty easy, can you give an example of your dataSource and upload a picture of how your pickers look? Then it'd be just a matter of parsing the Ints out of the strings. Provide this and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Check out my new answer. To make sure that your hours are "0 hour" or "3 hours", just make a tiny method that receives a number and decides if it's plural or not, or something of the sort. Those are just details. If you have questions, let me know.